# How can I get logcat on my device to show logs from all processes

Tags: android, logcat

I'm trying to write an app that reads all logs on my device.  I've got a client/service architecture, and I see log messages from both the client and service processes but I don't see any messages from any other applications on the phone (I do see other messages using the desktop logcat).

Do I need root?

## Code Snippets

#### Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
```

#### Log Reader

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -c").waitFor();

Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -v long *:*");
BufferedReader reader = 
    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
while (true) {
    String nextLine = reader.readLine();
    if (!nextLine.contains("LogWatcher-D")) {
        Log.w("LogWatcher-D", "See: " + nextLine);
    }

    // Process line
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On Android 4.1+, you can only access log messages logged by your process, unless you hold the `READ_LOGS` permission. That permission requires either that your app be signed by the same signing key that signed the device's firmware, or that your app is installed on the system partition.

Comment: @Hounshell: AFAIK, no. However, a user of a rooted device can move your app to the system partition, in which case you can hold `READ_LOGS`.

Comment: @CommonsWare: So if you install the app normally, with the aforementioned Permission, all you can see is the application log? (no system log?)

Comment: @Campiador: Correct, on 4.1 and higher.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Thanks. I have access to my device's kernel through UART. Can you please tell me which folder to move my app into?  I searched the net but could not find any answer, because I am a Linux noobie.

Comment: @Campiador: I haven't done it personally. I know that the right location is on the `system` partition, but that's it. Sorry!

Comment: @CommonsWare: I did it, the app should be moved from /data/app/ to /system/app/

Answer (score 2):

To read logs from other applications programmatically, you will need to assign the same android:sharedUserId in all apks' manifest files.

Comment: Downvoted because the answer doesn't answer the question (*all* logs) and is less complete than the older, already accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to access all logs for all applications without root. It requires enabling remote debugging. Take a look at the open source [rootless Logcat app](https://github.com/tananaev/rootless-logcat).